# Wanted to change text in html webpage using plain javascript using infinte loop which runs in every 1 sec, but the webpage get stuck when i load

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML snippet

and javascript file to handle the change

```js
const slideTitleArr =['financial Services', 'Management Services'];

function slidingTitle() {
    for (let i = 0; i>-1; i++) {
        if (i === slideTitleArr.length) {
            i=0;
        }
        setTimeout(function timer() {
            document.getElementById('sliding-title').innerHTML = slideTitleArr[i];
        }, i*1000);
    } 
}

window.onload =  slidingTitle()
```

```html
<h1>Trailblazing CRM  for <span id="sliding-title"style="color: white">financial services</span> </h1>
```

I don't know why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was crashing because you created an infinite loop (`i>-1`) which prevented the `setTimeout` from ever running ([here is useful post on the JS event loop/call stack](https://gist.github.com/jesstelford/9a35d20a2aa044df8bf241e00d7bc2d0)). You are looking for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). `setInterval()` will call a function every `n` seconds.

```js
const slideTitleArr = ['financial Services', 'Management Services'];
let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  i = i >= slideTitleArr.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;
  document.getElementById('sliding-title').innerHTML = slideTitleArr[i];
}, 1000);
```

```html
<h1>Trailblazing CRM for
  <span id="sliding-title">financial services</span>
</h1>
```